# Error installing GDAL in PyCharm

Tags: gdal, pycharm, pip

I've been trying to install GDAL for a month now in PyCharm. I use PyCharm, I like it, and I'm not switching to/adding Anaconda.

I keep getting the following error (screenshot below) on any GDAL or osgeo-related install. My pip is there and up to date, v. 18.1. Screenshot below of confirming this in command line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Luke...I got it installed via command prompt, so I can't reproduce the error message to copy/paste instead of screenshot. For some reason I have a "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6" folder and a "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6" folder, and something was wrong with the pip in one of them. So, I got gdal installed, but I installed it into the Arc folders in C:\Python27, so I probably broke my arcgis :-|   I assume I will know when I messed it up because running a script calling arcpy will crash? A clean re-install of arcgis should fix it?

Comment: @Luke, related question, but I can write it up as a separate question if that is preferred. I'm writing scripts in Python, and some of them I am turning into "tools" in ArcGIS to pass along to others on my team that don't use Python or any coding. My questions are [1] what is the best structure for my "C:\Python27" folder for handling ArcGIS and any additional libraries (e.g., GDAL); and [2] should everyone else on my team have the same folder structure I do to ensure they can run the script tools?

Comment: GDAL requires a specific version of numpy, as does ArcMap.  Unfortunately (at least on 10.3) the versions they each require are different, so installing GDAL breaks ArcMap.  You say you're not switching to Anaconda, but if you need to use GDAL it's all but necessary to do so in a separate Python environment from Arc's, which is exactly what Anaconda will allow you to achieve.

Comment: FWIW, I have GDAL installed in my Arc10.6 python libraries, and nothing has broken *yet*.  Does pandas have the same issue? I've had it installed for a while in the Arc python libraries, and it doesn't seem to have updated numpy

Comment: Not sure about pandas, I don't really use it.  I did get gdal to install into 10.3 back when I attempted it, but it would give me a numpy-related error when calling certain functions (like `band.ReadAsArray()` I think?).  But maybe 10.6 is indeed compatible

Comment: I've got a error when i tried to install GDAL library in PyCharm. I getting the same error(screenshot) from a while now and i didn't find anything anywhere. I got the latest version of PyCharm and i got updated the setuptools to version 40.6.3. Can anyone help me? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCFTz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCFTz.png)